# Python3: Append to list inside two for loops

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I have the following code, that sums up a maximum of 100 random numbers drawn from a normal distribution until it reaches -10 or +10:

```
import numpy as np
mylist=[]
summ = 0
for x in range(100):
    i = np.random.randn()
    summ += i
    mylist.append(i)
    if summ < -10 or summ >10:
        break
```

Now I want to run this 500 times, and thus create a list with 500 lists, each containing the numbers. I thought of putting this in another `for` loop:

```
for p in range(500):
    templist = []
    for x in range(100):
        i = np.random.randn()
        summ += i
        templist.append(i)
        if summ < -10 or summ >10:
            mylist.append(templist)
            break
```

Except that I don't know how to append the element i to the list now...

**Update:** I updated the code so the random numbers are first added to a temporary list `templist`, and as soon as the sum walks out the limits, it appends this list to `mylist`. However, not working still!

Comment: You want to loop 500 times, but create 200 lists?  How would this work?

Comment: typo, sorry! 500 times to get 500 lists!

Comment: Create another list outside of the `p` loop.  Start a new `mylist` inside the `p` loop, and append it to outer list when the `x` loop is done.

Comment: Do you want to create 500 lists with the current value of `i`? Then you don’t need to append it to the new list. Just initialize the list with it: `mylist.append([i])`

Comment: How do you handle the case if your sum does never reach the upper or lower bound? Is it intentional that not every sum of list elements is greater than 10 or lower than -10?

Comment: @Cani I updated the code. Did you mean like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = []
for p in range(500):
    new_list = []
    summ = 0
    for x in range(100):
        i = np.random.randn()
        summ += i
        new_list.append(i)
        if summ < -10 or summ >10:
            break
    mylist.append(new_list)
```

Comment: I like this code because it connects to what I already know. However, the lists inside `mylist` are mostly of size 1, which cannot be the case.

Comment: Updated. The `summ` did not be set to 0 in the previous code.

Comment: Of course! otherwise the `if` will always be true! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute any function 500 times and save the result in a list by using decorators. Just put your functionality inside a function:

```
import numpy as np

def execute_500_times(func):

    def multiplying_func(*args, **kwargs):
        list_of_results = list()
        for _ in range(500):
            list_of_results.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return list_of_results

    return multiplying_func

@execute_500_times
def myfunc():
    mylist=list()
    summ = 0
    for x in range(100):
        i = np.random.randn()
        summ += i
        mylist.append(i)
        if summ < -10 or summ >10:
            break

    return mylist

result = myfunc()
```

An advantage of this is that the decorator function can be reused for other functions as well instead of just modifying your original function.

Comment: probably a very nice solution, except that I am not at this level of python3-proficiency

Comment: @rororo: [this tutorial](https://dbader.org/blog/python-decorators) is a good starting point if you want to get into decorators.